# Cookie errors when embedding Google Maps into website

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, embed

I am trying to embed google maps into my website. To do this I went to the google maps website and clicked "share" and the clicked "embed a map" and then copied the html to my clipboard and pasted it into my website code. When I run the website I get lots of errors saying "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute".

This might be a stupid question but what does this mean and how do I solve this issue? Everything I have read so far has not answered my question.

Answer (score -1):

Try accepting the cookies of google maps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How should I do that? Like in my code or from google chrome?